# Yii : Unstable getState function result when call setState/Set Session more then 1 time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii

For Example, i have session 'globalunit', and i want to set that session value use setState function. so i make actionSetUnit and actionGetUnit function in my Controller class to be called in my View class by ajax

```
 //to set globalunit
 public function actionSetUnit(){
   if (isset($_POST['unit']) && $_POST['unit'] !== null){
         Yii::app()->user->setState('globalunit',$_POST['unit']);
         echo 'globalunit value now is :'.Yii::app()->user->getState('globalunit');
    }
 }

 //to get globalunit
 public function actionGetUnit(){
    echo 'globalunit value now is :'.Yii::app()->user->getState('globalunit');
 }
```

i often call actionSetUnit in my view, when i change/click my combo unit in my view. but when i call getUnit function in my view to show globalunit value, the result/respons unstable. sometime the respons is true according the last unit i choose in combo Unit. sometime the respons is false (not change according the value of the last unit i choose in combo unit) :(... 
Maybe i too much call setState function to set value session with same name. 
any missing in my code??

Answer (score 1):

Make sure only to set the state when the $_POST is filled

```
 //to set globalunit
 public function actionSetUnit(){
    if (isset($_POST['unit']) && $_POST['unit'] !== null)
        Yii::app()->user->setState('globalunit',$_POST['unit']);
 }
```

I guess you are overwriting it sometimes with an empty value. Try to Yii::trace() or Yii::log() your $_POST value to ensure it is filled every call.

Comment: i had edited my code like above, i try to sent the globalunit value after i set globalunit from View.
When i call actionsetunit, it's work (i check in firebug response,equal to what i sent to actionSetUnit), the $_POST['unit'] always filled,but if i call actionGetUnit(),the value is wrong (not same with the actionSetUnit response)..

Comment: Sounds like your session is not working correct. Do you use cookies or session id? Does your browser accept cookies?

Comment: yes,that's default setting browser. i never change that setting